# Laravel task scheduling command frequency delay or offset

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Is there a way to delay or offset a scheduled command from the proposed frequency options?

e.g:

```
$schedule->command('GetX')->everyTenMinutes(); --> run at 9:10, 9:20, 9:30
$schedule->command('GetY')->everyTenMinutes(); --> run at 9:15, 9:25, 9:35
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `delay` function when scheduling tasks.

But `when` method can be used to **schedule a task every 10 minutes, delay 5 minutes**:

```
// this command is scheduled to run if minute is 05, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55
// the truth test is checked every minute
$schedule->command('foo:bar')->everyMinute()->when(function () {
    return date('i') - 5 % 10 == 0;
});
```

Follow this rule, you can schedule a task every **x** minutes, delay **y** minutes

```
$schedule->command('foo:bar')->everyMinute()->when(function () {
    return date('i') - y % x == 0;
});
```

If it gets difficult, the direct way you can simply write a custom Cron schedule. It is the easier way to understand without getting headache when you read the code later.

```
$schedule->command('foo:bar')->cron('05,15,25,35,45,55 * * * *');
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben, `date('m')` should be `date('i')`. I changed `date('m') - y % x == 0` to `substr(date('i'), -1) == 0` and `substr(date('i'), -1) == 5` since it was easier to understand for me.

Comment: You probably missed parentheses `return (date('m') - 5) % 10 == 0;`